# Intent always null onStartCommand

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

I have following code

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null) {
        Log.i("INTENT", intent.getAction().toString());
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

but it always returns `NullPointerException` on line:

```
Log.i("INTENT", intent.getAction().toString());
```

Why? I'm checking above if "intent" variable is not null. If that's the case execute following code. But i still got nullpointerexception.

Service is started from activity like that:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably getAction() returns null. Try checking it in a String.
Something like `String s = intent.getAction().toString();` and check if its null or not.

Comment: Because i also have broadcast which starts this service, and i would like to distinguish between service started in activity or service started with broadcast.

Comment: @Wamasa I tried. It still returns nullpointerexception. If i remove getAction(), service is started okay.

Wtf?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because `intent.getAction()` seems to return `null`.

You should extend your check to this:

```
if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
```

If you want to add an Action to your intent you need to call [setAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
i.setAction("foo");
startService(i);
```

Comment: Your the man. It's working. I needed to extend my "if" check.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar stack，add the check

```
intent.getAction() != null
```

it worked.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp, PID: 17676
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp.CountService@f6049d4 with Intent { cmp=com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp/.CountService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3698)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:198)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp.CountService.onStartCommand(CountService.java:24)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3679)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:198) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1668) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17676 SIG: 9